# Difference between аренда and бронирование

Tags: значения

I am writing a database for room rent. How should I call it - аренда помещений or бронирование помещений? What is the main difference between those two words? I have always thought that it means the same.

Comment: Wow, my first downvote! =) How can I improve the question? Or maybe it's absolutely irrelevant?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I can assume that the phrase "I just have no time to look it up in the dictionaries" is quite provocative)

Comment: I believe that the question is valid and will remain valid even after obliterating that phrase :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are completely different things.

By бронирование you declare that you intend to pay for some service or product. Since the moment of the бронирование, the seller has no right to offer this product to another party unless you cancel the бронирование. Бронирование can be free of charge or for money, but the sum may be less than the total price of the product or service.

So speaking about a room you can забронировать it before moving to it so that it will not be offered to other clients. Yet if you change your mind you can cancel the бронирование before starting using the room and get money back.

Comment: Бронирование is booking or reservation; Аренда is rent. You can _book a car for rent_ that is (за)бронировать прокат машины. The same applies to rooms.

Answer (score 0):

You need word «Аренда».
«Бронирование» is reservation or booking.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What if my application helps perform reservation, but the reservation is actually a room reservation (equivalent to rent)?

Comment: The most suitable name for your database is "Аренда помещений" (rent). And when a user wants to book/make a reservation, then provide this user with a button with title "Забронировать".

Comment: Yes, you are right, @RafaelOsipov, this is how it al should be arranged.